# How to Compare Values from 2 Arrays to Filter Out Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, foreach

I'm having a really difficult time figuring out this problem. I have two arrays (`cars` and `active_filters`). The cars array contains html li tags with attributes such as car type, number of seats, price, etc. The active_filters array contains objects related to which filters the user interacted and will be used for which cars to display or hide.

Example: When looking at `active filters` for id `data-type`, the value property includes a list of all car codes that the user is wanting to display. If a cars data-type is not found or equal to one of these car codes, my goal is to hide these cars by adding class `type` to each car. So in this case, these cars should have class `filtered-out-by-car-type` added.

I'm noticing the performance is pretty slow with what I currently have below. Also, I'm stuck on how to access the specific `type` from active_filters associated with the car that is found. Appreciate any help! Thanks so much!!

**Cars:**

```
<li data-partner-code="EZ" data-type="XXAR" data-seats="2" data-bags="2" data-prepaid="Y" data-transmission="Automatic" data-unlimited-miles="Y" data-price="84.81" class="listing">
<li data-partner-code="AV" data-type="SFAR" data-seats="4" data-bags="2" data-prepaid="N" data-transmission="Automatic" data-unlimited-miles="Y" data-price="125.54" class="listing">
<li data-partner-code="BU" data-type="CCAR" data-seats="4" data-bags="2" data-prepaid="N" data-transmission="Automatic" data-unlimited-miles="N" data-price="65.42" class="listing">
<li data-partner-code="BU" data-type="CCAR" data-seats="4" data-bags="2" data-prepaid="N" data-transmission="Automatic" data-unlimited-miles="N" data-price="65.42" class="listing">
<li data-partner-code="FX" data-type="MCAR" data-seats="2" data-bags="1" data-prepaid="N" data-transmission="Automatic" data-unlimited-miles="N" data-price="32.00" class="listing">
```

**Active Filters:**

```
{id: "data-seats", value: "1", type: "filtered-out-by-seats"}
{id: "data-bags", value: "2", type: "filtered-out-by-bags"}
{id: "data-partner-code", value: "ET,EY,BU", type: "filtered-out-by-company"}
{id: "data-type", value: "IFAR,SFAR,PGAR,RFAR,FFAR,XXAR", type: "filtered-out-by-car-type"}
```

**Current Code:**

```
cars.forEach(function(car)
{
    var found = active_filters.find(function(filter) {
        var filter_value = filter.value.split(","); // getting unique value
        for (var i=0; i<filter_value.length; i++)
        {
            if (car.attr(filter.id) === filter_value[i])
            {
                return car; // Why is this returning active_filters element instead of car?
            }
        }
    });

    // Todo: How can I access active_filters.type associated to the car that was found?
    if (!found)
    {
        car.addClass(active_filters.type); // ?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements aren't completely clear to me, but the problem seems tailor-made for basic array operations, so perhaps I can offer a framework for solving it that you can fill in with the details.

First, it seems that the basic idea is to filter to `cars` array to a subset. It turns out there's an Array method just for that called, naturally, `filter`

```
const filtered_cars = cars.filter(car => {
    // This function will get passed each car in turn. Return
    // true if the car should be kept in the list, false otherwise.
});
```

Now, for each car, I think you want to check all of the active filters. If any of the active filters match, the car should be kept. Again, there's an Array method, in this case it's `some`.

```
const filtered_cars = cars.filter(car => {
    return active_filters.some(filter => {
        // Within this function, we have a car variable, and a filter
        // variable. We want to return true if the car matches the
        // filter, false otherwise
    });
});
```

It appears from your description that each active filter may have multiple
values, separated by commas. We need to extract those into an array. We can also extract the appropriate car attribute for the filter.

```
const filtered_cars = cars.filter(car => {
    return active_filters.some(filter => {
        const values = filter.value.split(",");
        const attribute = car.getAttribute(filter.id);
        // Return true if the attribute is in the set of values
    });
});
```

Once again we can make use of `some`

```
const filtered_cars = cars.filter(car => {
    return active_filters.some(filter => {
        const values = filter.value.split(",");
        const attribute = car.getAttribute(filter.id);
        return values.some(value => {
            return value === attribute;
        });
    });
});
```

At this point, we have reduced the cars array to only those elements that match the filters, but we haven't added the type to those cars that didn't make the filter. To do that, we have to replace the first `some` with a `forEach` to ensure that we loop through all the filters instead of stopping at the first match. Also we want to either add or remove the special class as appropriate.

```
const filtered_cars = cars.filter(car => {
    let keep_car = false;
    active_filters.forEach(filter => {
        const values = filter.value.split(",");
        const attribute = car.getAttribute(filter.id);
        const matched = values.some(value => {
            return value === attribute;
        });
        car.classList.toggle(filter.type, !matched);
        keep_car = keep_car || matched;
    });
    return keep_car;
});
```

Like I said, I'm not sure if that code is exactly what you want, as I may have misunderstood the problem. But hopefully it's enough to get you past the current road block.

Comment: Hi Stephen. WOW! Thank you so much, this is AMAZING! Quick question: I noticed that all filter id's are working correctly, except for data-seats and data-bags. If data-seats value is 10, and I want to addClass filter.type to all cars that are less than 10 where would I make that change? I'm thinking this in matched

Comment: I figured it out http://prntscr.com/jekgak :) THANK YOU SO SO MUCH!!!!!!!